# Horizontally expanded table created dynamically instead of many joins for performance gain

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider a products table, where some info like TITLE and BRAND are kept in a huge "translations" table in multiple languages.

```
tblTranslations
    ROW_ID
    COL_NAME
    LANG
    VALUE
```

Since which languages will be used is dynamic, keeping titles for desired languages in the main table like TITLE_EN, TITLE_FR is not an option. So we have complicated queries like below:

```
SELECT
    P.ID,
    (...)
    T1.VALUE AS TITLE,
    T2.VALUE AS BRAND
FROM 
    tblProducts P
-- first join for TITLEs in the selected language
LEFT JOIN 
    tblTranslations T1 ON T1.ROW_ID = P.ID 
                       AND T1.COL_NAME = 'TITLE' 
                       AND T1.LANG = '{$selectedLang}'
-- second join for BRANDs
LEFT JOIN 
    tblTranslations T2 ON T2.ROW_ID = P.ID 
                       AND T2.COL_NAME = 'BRAND' 
                       AND T2.LANG = '{$selectedLang}'
WHERE (...)
```

This was an overly simplified example, our real life queries have many other tables joined for dynamic attributes etc., and this makes our websites start crawling on the ground.

My question: is it a better approach to dynamically create a table and use it for SELECTs only? This table will be updated when the main data is updated, and would be re-created when a new language is added.

```
tblProductsDynamic
    ID
    TITLE_EN
    TITLE_FR
    BRAND_EN
    BRAND_FR
    (...)
```

```
SELECT
    ID,
    TITLE_{$selectedLang} AS TITLE,
    BRAND_{$selectedLang} AS BRAND
FROM 
    tblProductsDynamic
```

Will this horizontally expanded table give more performance since it lacks all the tiresome joins?

Comment: You didn't tag this with a particular database but you might want to look into what Oracle refers to as a [materialized view"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/basic-materialized-views.html#GUID-A7AE8E5D-68A5-4519-81EB-252EAAF0ADFF). This is normally used in a data warehousing context but it might provide a solution to the problem you're facing. Other database engines probably have similar solutions, although the names may vary.

Comment: Are there proper indexes on the tables?

Comment: Consider a translation table which has all `products table`s columns plus `LANG`. Just join on ROW_ID and LANG = target lang.

Comment: @sticky-bit I intentionally excluded indexes from my question because I think that's not the focus here, but please consider we live in a perfect world and there are proper indexes.

Comment: @Serg good idea, but the translations table is holding data for other tables, not just products, and it is as large as "those tables x translatable columns x used langs". We also use "attributes" table and join them multiple times. I simplified the structure in the question.

Comment: @Blameself: Indexes are the number one concern when it comes to performance improvements, not denormalization. Since you kind of evaded my question, I have a feeling, that there's more room of improvement for you there...

Comment: Just curious, why left joins? What happens when no translation is available?

Comment: @sticky bit yes we have indexes and we are looking for other angles to improve performance. Since there are too many variables when it comes to database queries, I just wanted to focus on one point when I asked my question. I'm grateful for your interest though.

Comment: @Alex There is always a translation since even the default lang expression is kept on that table. But sometimes we don't join and use the column on the main table instead, if default language is desired.

Comment: Would `INNER JOIN` not be more efficient? Additionally, this may be the case where `WITH( NOLOCK )` hint (on translation table joins) may be of value, since this is a high contention read only table.

Comment: From "those tables x translatable columns x used langs" I gather that your translation table has PK made up of ~4 columns (TableName, ColName, Lang, ID, ...) and a single data column. If this is the case then, **IMO**, pivoting and/or splitting this into multiple smaller tables should give performance advantage, as you will eliminating some of the key columns.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, pre-computing values is going to be a performance win when you query the data. You have to balance that against the cost:

- Maintaining the unpivoted table is going to be somewhat expensive.
- It is going to be especially expensive when a new language is added.
- You may have data integrity problems, caused by lags in the construction of the summary table.
- Maintaining the triggers, stored procedures or whatever for the summary table complicates the code base.

That said, your `left join`s should not be particularly expensive with the right indexes. I would first want to investigate a solution using the base tables you have described. Only then would I think about options for summarizing the data.